# How to group transformed inputs?

Tags: msbuild

I have a file type that need to be generated and then validated, using 2 separate tools. I want to do it as incrementally as possible, so I want to create a 0-file marker that remembers when the generated file was last validated. I managed to have the generation re-run only on modified files, but not the validation.

For example, suppose this is the .targets:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Validate" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyItem Include="itemA" />
    <MyItem Include="itemB" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Generate"
          Inputs="@(MyItem)"
          Outputs="@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyItem)" DestinationFiles="@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen')" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Validate" DependsOnTargets="Generate"
          Inputs="@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen')"
          Outputs="@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen.validated')">
    <!-- Do validation stuff... -->
    <Touch AlwaysCreate="true" Files="@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen.validated')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I run it the first time, it generates and validates both items - that's good:

```
> msbuild
Generate:
  Copying file from "itemA" to "itemA.gen".
  Copying file from "itemB" to "itemB.gen".
Validate:
  Creating "itemA.gen.validated" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
  Creating "itemB.gen.validated" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
```

Run it again, and nothing is done - that's great:

```
> MSBuild
Generate:
Skipping target "Generate" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
Validate:
Skipping target "Validate" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
```

Now change just itemA:

```
> touch itemA
> MSBuild
Generate:
Building target "Generate" partially, because some output files are out of date with respect to their input files.
  Copying file from "itemA" to "itemA.gen".     <<<<< Good - MSBuild knows not to generate itemB.gen
Validate:
  Touching "itemA.gen.validated".
  Touching "itemB.gen.validated".    <<<< Bad - how can I tell MSBuild to skip validation of itemB
```

So, how can I tell MSBuild to run my `Validate` target partially too?

Comment: not sure if this can be done. But in cases like this, instead of spending hours of searching the correct msbuild wizardry, I usually resolve to using CodeTaskFactory and write two lines of C# to compare timestamps. In this case you can probably even get away with property functions, eg make properties like `<TimeStamp1>$([System.IO.File]::GetLastWriteTime('@(MyItem->%(Filename).gen.validated)').ToString())</TimeStamp1>`, compare them, and call `touch` only when they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Keep the transformed input in a separate ItemGroup. Like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Validate" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <MyItem Include="itemA" />
    <MyItem Include="itemB" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Generate"
          Inputs="@(MyItem)"
          Outputs="@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen')">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyItem)" DestinationFiles="@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen')" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <Generated Include="@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen')" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Validate" DependsOnTargets="Generate"
          Inputs="@(Generated)"
          Outputs="@(Generated->'%(Filename).gen.validated')" >
    <!-- Do validation stuff... -->
    <Touch AlwaysCreate="true" Files="@(Generated->'%(Filename).gen.validated')" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I still wish I could avoid repeating `@(MyItem->'%(Filename).gen')` 3 times...